# NGINX Revers Proxy subfolder URI path Issue

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have NGINX revers proxy implemented to access backend web service. Please note that the Web service is hosted on a different server, not NGINX server.
Web Service access URL in http://10.2.4.5/abcd/

My Nginx Config is

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  10.2.4.5, localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location /{

    
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;


    proxy_pass http://10.2.4.5/abcd/;

        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

}

when I try to access the web page through NGINX, page is not loading correctly. Images are not loading.
I have tried by removing the `/` at the end of URI path in proxy_pass directive. But issue was not resolved.
How Can I fix this issue.

Comment: It is likely your application running at `10.2.4.5` which is generating bad URLs for page resources. Check the HTML source of the page your application generates and check the resource URLs. If they are not correct, then you need to fix it in your application.

Comment: @Tero Kilkanen But if I try to access the same web site in the browser with  [Link](http://NGINXproxy IP) and then add the **/abcd**, web site perfectly load. of cause I have to change the nginx config Proxy_pass directive to `Proxy_pass http://10.2.4.5/;`